# How can I change the cursor moving on ctrlp?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, plugin-ctrlp

I want to change the key mapping when I run CtrlP. For example, if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to run CtrlP, type in something, and try to move the cursor to choose a file, I want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to move down, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to move up.

Is this possible? How can I change the key mapping in the CtrlP window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictonary variable `g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings` that is read by CtrlP.  You just need to specify the keys you want to change. Read `:h g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings` for more info.

In order to get what you describe in your question try this in your vimrc file:

```
let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
  \ 'PrtSelectMove("j")':   ['<c-j>', '<down>'],
  \ 'PrtSelectMove("k")':   ['<c-k>', '<up>'],
  \ }
```

But that is already the default. Maybe you want to switch j and k (did I misread your question?) so you can try it the other way round if you want:

```
let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
  \ 'PrtSelectMove("j")':   ['<c-k>', '<down>'],
  \ 'PrtSelectMove("k")':   ['<c-j>', '<up>'],
  \ }
```