# How can I change the cursor moving on fzf?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-fzf

Similar to [the question about ctrlp](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16670/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-moving-on-ctrlp), I would like to know how to change the key remapping to move the cursor on fzf library.

Right now, only the ctrl + k works to move the cursor upward, but all the downside movement does not work.

So how can I define the key remapping?

Answer (score 5):

this is the default mapping of up and down in fzf:

- down : ctrl-j  ctrl-n  down
- up : ctrl-k  ctrl-p  up

Most people don't have problem with this. If you really really want to add your own setting, you need to change enviroment variable:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS='--bind=ctrl-w:up,ctrl-m:down'
```

above setting will bind `ctrl-w` to `up`, `ctrl-m` to `down`. check `man fzf` for detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--bind` to change mappings to everything you like:

So something along the lines of this should work for you:

```
map <silent> <F2> :call fzf#run({'source': 'rg --files --column --no-heading --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*"', 'sink': 'e', 'down': '~30%', 'options': '--bind ctrl-o:up,ctrl-l:down'})<cr>
```

Of course only the `options` part is important for your question, but I wanted to keep the context.

For every keymap option available check `man fzf`

Answer (score -1):

I use `Ctrlp` as its likely to be much  more stable and bugfree and pretty comparable to fzf (with `ctrlp-py-matcher`), and probably lot more options for customization: https://github.com/weiliu89/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/doc/ctrlp.txt

`fzf.vim` also seems to have default bindings: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/56

Hopefully, `fzf` will be integrated to `ctrlp` someday soon..